# How to define neighborhoods in hexagonal Self-Organizing Maps (SOM)

Tags: scala, cluster-analysis, self-organizing-maps

I'm trying to implement a bi-dimensional SOM with shrinking neighborhoods, but to avoid computing the neighborhood function to each neuron for every input, I want to define the neighbors for each neuron since the construction of the lattice. I mean, when creating the SOM, I would add each neighbor to a list within the neurons, so when a neuron is selected as BMU, I only have to apply the neighborhood function to the neurons in that BMU's list.
The problem is to define the topology of an hexagonal lattice within a bi-dimensional array, which is the structure that I'm using for the SOM, cause to achieve the hexagonal distribution I would have to do something like this:

*n1*   | *null* |  *n2*  | *null* | *n3*
*null* |  *n4*  | *null* |  *n5*  | *null*
*n6*   | *null* |  *n7*  | *null* | *n8*

Is it correct to create the array like that or there is a way to create a normal array and adjust de indexes?

Comment: Not sure what "BMU" is. Anyway, here is how you can represent the cells of a hexagonal grid by an ordinary array: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49131014/2707792). The formula for converting between array indices and coordinates is given there too.
I'm not sure what all those `null`s are doing in there: the only place you ever need `null` is when interacting with legacy java code.

Comment: BMU stands for "Best-Matching Unit", a reference to the neuron that is the closest to a given input. The nulls were to represent the idea of how the array should be distributed. I'll check your link, thank you